# Ember, observer listening to an property in another controller

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

I have two controllers Tags and Reports. 
Tags Controller need's to observe data property on Reports.
However the data property is async and updated after a call on the server. 
How do I get the property inside Reports?

I'm trying to do something like the following:

```
ReportsController({
  data: null,
  actions: {
    onAsyncCall: function(updatedData) {
      this.set('data', updatedData);
    }
  }
});

TagsController({
  reportsController: Ember.inject.controller('reports'),
  doSomethingDataUpdate: Ember.observer('reportsController.data', function() {
    this.set('tagProperties', this.get('reportsController.data'));
  }
});
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: tangential, but I would do `tagProperties: Ember.computed.alias('reportsController.data')`

Comment: Wouldn't `Ember.computed.readOnly` be better in this case?

Comment: Why the readOnly? He wants the exact same thing on another instance of controller. alias is a good choice.

Answer (score 1):

So I figured a way out. Instead of having TagsController inject ReportsController. I reversed it and had Tagscontroller injected into Reports.

After the async call, I updated the property on the Tagscontroller which is now observable. problem solved.

```
ReportsController({
  tagsController: Ember.inject.controller('reports.tags'),
  actions: {
    onAsyncCall: function(updatedData) {
      this.set('tagsController.data', updatedData);
    }
  }
}); 

TagsController({
  data: null,
  doSomethingDataUpdate: Ember.observer('data', function() {
    this.set('tagProperties', this.get('data'));
  }
});
```

**Update**:
So I found a better solution. 
[communicating between components](http://emberigniter.com/communication-between-distant-components/)

Basically I needed to use a service, particularly a service that extended Ember.Events.

This way whenever I had an async update in my reports it'd trigger an action to update my tags. I think I read somewhere that observer and computed are only fired after this.get(). So it wasn't really observing my changes I was looking for. Thanks everyone for the help.

Comment: I dont understand the purpose of "tagProperties" An extra observer that does nothing.. Btw if u have more of these common functions. I'd reccommend making a "mixin" and wraping the controllers with the mixin.

Comment: Sorry you're right. This is just pseudo code. "Tag properties" is soemthing else I wanted to set.